# How to get sublist's head using lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a value:

```
my :: [(A, Either B [C])]
```

and I want to get `[(A, C)]` from it using [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). The result items are items from `my` that:

1. the second item in tuples is `Right [C]`
2. the list in this `Right [C]` has at least 1 item, so the result get the first (head) item from it

I know how to get the `[C]` but I don't know how to get `[(A, C)]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

```
my ^.. each . runFold (second (Fold (_Right . _head)))
```

The idea is that `_Right . _head` is a fold that selects a `C` from an `Either B [C]`.  You can make it select an `(A, C)` from an `(A, Either B [C])`, using `second` from `Control.Arrow`.  However, to do this, you need to reify the fold (i.e., turn it into a newtype with an `Arrow` instance) using `Fold` and then unreify it with `runFold`.  The resulting fold specializes to:

```
runFold (second (Fold (_Right . _head))) :: Fold (A, Either B [C]) (A,C)
```

which selects either zero or one instances of `(A,C)`, and you can compose it with `each` to fold over a traversable container, like a list:

```
runFold (second (Fold (_Right . _head))) :: Fold [(A, Either B [C])] (A,C)
```

to select all of the `(A,C)` from the container's elements.

Sample code:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Arrow

my :: [(Int, Either Double [Char])]
my = [(1, Right "apple"), (2, Left 1.5), (3, Right "bear"), (4, Right "")]

main = do
  print $ my ^.. each . runFold (second (Fold (_Right . _head)))
```